# How to pass a result from a function that requires GUI input (python)?

Tags: python

I'm writing a python script that takes user input through a GUI and then passes that along to a function that basically reads through text files and checks that what the user requested is there.  This function returns an array with True or False for each check.

I want to use this array in a different function (def markup()), but if I call it without giving the function the user input, I get an error.

Is there a way for me to store the results of this function and pass it without needing the user input each time?

Pseudo code:

```
def clickButton():

    userInput = [A,B,C,D,E]
    textCheck(userInput)

def textCheck(userInput):

    *code for checking text creates an array named allResults*
    return allResults

def markup():

    results = textCheck()
    print(results)
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean? Doesn't the functionality of your GUI rely on the user input? Perhaps you want a default argument value in `clickButton()`?

Comment: I think what you're asking is if there's a way for it to reference what was used the last time the program was used. To do this, I'd suggest writing the values to a file, and checking that file for the values. Those can be overridden by user input and determined at the time when they click the button to accept values.

Comment: It does rely on user input. But I've taken the user input with clickButton() and used it in textCheck(). The problem is trying to use the return of textCheck() in a third function; I'd like to use it without re-sending all of the user input again. Can I save 'allResults' so that it's accessible by other functions?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to manage allResults as a persistent object.  One way is to pass the results everywhere as a parameter, such that whatever thread is executing always has a handle to the list.  Another way is to (*shudder*) make it a global variable -- this is somewhat dangerous as a habit, but may be the easiest for you to implement and maintain.  You can also create a `Results` class and instantiate an object that persists as long as you need it.

I can't recommend one over another without having the flow of the main program.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up calling markup(allResults) at the end of textChecker(). It worked.